# How to calculate nbits from powlimit

Tags: altcoin, genesis-block, nbits

I remember some where was table and python scrypt for do this , when reinstall my debian i was lose this script.

Example we hv uint256S("00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"); 
what is = 0x1d00ffff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the conversion can be found on [the bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty).

Essentially, the first byte indicates the number of trailing 0 bytes (minus 3 for some reason). The remaining 3 bytes are the next 3 bytes of the target.

So `0x1d00fffff` has `0x00ffff` followed by `0x1d - 3 = 26` trailing 0 bytes with the whole thing padded out to 32 bytes. So the final result is `0x00000000ffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.